# how to fixed set data type as text of query parameters in ssrs report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, types, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a `SSRS` report file which contains the `multiselect dropdownlist` and using `stored procedure`. In a `query desinger`> `Define Query Parameters`, i am passing a multiple values seperating by `comma` and set `datatype` `text` so it is showing me correct output. When i set `datatype` `Auto` and giving multiple values it is not showing the correct output but correct output if i give a single value.

> The problem is the values comes from code behind is in 2,23 
>   string format and i need to set the datatype as `text` in define query parameters.

The SSRS `define query parameters data type` picture:[image: In a opening stage]

[image: When i select <code>text</code> output comes correct.]
[image]

If select `Auto` eg. [image]:

Output is Nothing eg. [image]:

If passing single value,it is working for it eg.-[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the query designer is goofy with multi strings - I think the format is something like `"22", "2"` or `" ""22"", ""2"" "`. Do you really need it to work with this designer? When you use the parameter in the actual report, it works differently (and correctly) so you may be wasting time worrying about it.

Comment: Actually passing the multiple values gives wrong `output` whereas right `output` in a single value to the Report from the `code behind` just like a `query designer`. So i am trying to set the `parameter as` `text` to solve this problem.